# How to get an old beer sign to work again?

Tags: arduino, voltage, led

Has anyone tried to upgrade an old beer / cigarette sign before? I'm a total electronics noob, and I got my hands on [one of these old Coors signs](https://www.ebay.com/itm/VINTAGE-COORS-BEER-DIGITAL-LED-SCROLLING-SIGN-GREAT-CONDITION-RARE-MAN-CAVE-/184456559138) that has a 45x7 LED display board. The board has what appears to be 9 input pins, unsure of how they work. Am I stuck with junk, or is there a way to reverse engineer the inputs and build a new driver with an Arduino? Giving a 3.3V or 5V HIGH signal to any/all of the pins doesn't seem to light up the board. Wondering if I just need a higher voltage or something.

[image: picture of input pins]

Comment: Hmm your picture doesn't really show us anything other than that maybe someone got a bit stabbity with a capacitor there.  It's a *possible* project, but it might be out of your skill range if you're not already good at both programming and electronics.

Comment: Something on the other side of that board has been pushed very hard so it ripped all the pads and plated-through holes off. Also looks like some Neanderthal has been been fiddling around with a soldering iron and has damaged the shrink sleeve on the capacitor. Does not bode well.

Comment: You might be able to guess at how to communicate with it based on the chips on the other side if it's old enough, but more likely you'd have to reverse engineer just the electrical interface with the LED array and deduce how it's meant to be controlled, then build your own control circuit rather than trying to reverse engineer the entire control scheme.  Thats more something for a motivated engineer to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback folks! For context, I am a software engineer trying my luck with an EE project. My main goal at this point is to get the LED board to light up at all. Is there anything I can do (tools I can buy, etc.) to sus out what voltage is needed to power the display?

Comment: Yes plenty of people have refurbished and updated these types of signs and others (bus, store marquees, train station schedule boards, basketball score signs) of various sizes. Depending on the parts on the board this can be simple to insane. Some of these simple signs have a known hd44780 type protocol. 16V Caps likely means 12V is used somewhere. There is physical damage and signs of someone attempting some sort of solder work. So you may have a dud. You need more pictures, clear in focus ones. Look for ICs and Google their datasheets.

Comment: Start finding the Gnd, its most probably the minus pole of these capacitors. Then look where is the plus pole of capacitor going, does it leads to 9 pin connector or is it going to some regulator (IC)? You may try to connect voltage source (3V3 or 5V) directly on these capacitors. Expect the power source about 1A at least is necessary.

Comment: If the plus pole of caps leads to 9pin connector directly, this will be the plus supply pin. If the plus pole of caps leads to regulator/rectifier you must go next until you get to connector (plus supply pin). The minus supply pin should be minus caps pole, measure with ohm-meter.